# Is hemp oil the same as CBD oil?

Tags: cancer, supplement, oil, marijuana

1. **Hemp oil** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemp_oil
2. **CBD oil**

[image]

It looks like CBD oil is made of hemp. Are they any major differences between **hemp oil** and **CBD oil** or are they pretty much the same?

Comment: It looks like had you read any of those sites, you would have your answer. Why don't you try that, and if something is still confusing (and pertinent to health), edit your question to include the specifics.

Comment: I'm afraid I know too little about the difference between marijuana, cannabis, hemp and CBD to actually understand the consequences. I'll try anyway. And then... Even if I assume that CBD oil is made of hemp - does it mean that "oil made of hemp" and "hemp oil" are the same? (who knows what is the exact manufacturing process)

Comment: The difference between "oil made of hemp" and "hemp oil" is a matter of language, not health. :)

Answer (score 5):

### Official source of information

http://www.thehia.org/Resources/PressReleases/HIA-position-CBD-FINAL.pdf

> Hemp seed oil does not contain any significant quantity of CBD.       Hemp fiber and seed cultivars contain relatively minimal 
>   CBD and CBD production from such plants should not be considered a primary  product.

---

### More links

http://www.chronictherapy.co/hemp-oil-vs-cbd-oil-whats-the-difference-2/

> Because the plants are related, some unscrupulous sellers of hemp oil are trying to market it for its medicinal value, which is negligible.

http://www.mintpressnews.com/hemp-oil-versus-cbd-oil-whats-the-difference/193962/

> Consumers often confuse hemp oil with CBD oil because both are low in THC and contain CBD.

---

It took me a while to wrap my head around all these quirks - I'm so detached from the nature :)

Answer (score 4):

Hemp oil is made from the seeds of the cannabis plants. These typically contain almost no cannabinoids, like THC or CBD. CBD-oil is any oil, not only hemp oil, enriched with CBD. The industry seems to prefer hemp-oil for that apparently. Ordinary, non-treated hemp seed oil is very low in CBD.

Cannabinoids are found in the stem, leaves and in greatest concentration in the flowering parts of the plant. To repeat: the seeds from which the oil is made do contain CBD, but only in trace amounts.

That means ordinary hemp seed oil does not contain CBD in meaningful quantities. Since hemp seed oil is a valuable source of fatty acids in a very nice relation to one another, it is often considered "healthy" on its own. But to get hemp seed oil with CBD, you need to bring the CBD from an external source into the oil. That is possible and seems like a natural choice since CBD is fat soluble and needs a carrier for the consumer to ingest it in meaningful dosage.

```
Feature                      Hemp Seed Oil                      Cannabidiol Oil
Plant species of origin      Industrial hemp (Cannabis sativa)  Industrial hemp 
                             strains with high CBD content      strains with low CBD content    (Cannabis sativa) 
Parts used to produce oil    Hemp seeds                         Hemp flowers, leaves
Method of production         Cold pressing                      CO2 (non-toxic) solvent extraction
Purified                     Filtered                           Yes
Independent laboratory       Not on THC content,                Yes on CBD and THC 
analysis and certification   but on fatty acid profile          content
Cannabinoid content Low CBD Rich CBD, Low THC
Food supplement uses         Healthy source of monounsaturated  To support general well-being, 
                             and essential fatty acids          relaxing
Does it produce a 'high'?    No (THC not present in the seeds)  No (Guaranteed low levels of THC)
Is it a legal food supplement?  Yes                             Yes
```

Source for table: [What’s the difference between hemp seed oil and cannabidiol oil (CBD)?](https://www.healthspan.co.uk/advice/whats-the-difference-between-hemp-seed-oil-and-cannabidiol-oil-cbd)

The legal advice in that table was quoted as is. It might be different where you live. According to [WebMD: All About CBD Oil](https://www.webmd.com/pain-management/ss/slideshow-cbd-oil) CBD might still be illegal in Idaho, Dakota and Nebraska. Worldwide there might be similarly crazy places.